Databricks Asset Bunde - Passing parameters to python code in job
I am deploying a Databricks Asset Bundle to do an ETL job. As part of this, I am making a small table from some master data in a parquet file, which is in my repo.
I want to pass the file_path as a variable defined in my jobs yaml files with dynamic insertion of user and environment variables.
I tried the following:
With this repo:
My repo structure:
databricks.yml
masterdata/
├── my_file.parquet
src/
├── my_script.py
resources/
├── my_job.yml

And this code:
file_path = <file_path>

df = spark.read.parquet(file_path)

and this yaml:
- task_key: station_table_generation
  job_cluster_key: job_cluster
  notebook_task: 
    notebook_path: ../src/curated/station.py
    parameters: 
      - name: station_file
        default: file:/Workspace/Users/${workspace.current_user.userName}/.bundle/${bundle.name}/${bundle.target}/files/masterdata/my_file.parquet

I dont know how to call parameters for the job in the code.

did you try dbutils.widgets.get("station_file") in your notebook?

this is what I ended up going with, thanks for the reply.

To close the issue, I'm adding the comment as a reply.
Did you try dbutils.widgets.get("station_file") in your notebook?
